# Java | Split words and round brackets with its content into elements of a String Array using regex

Tags: java, arrays, regex

Hopefully you can help me out, since I'm really bad at regex, so

Given these examples of `String` input patterns:

- `"string1 string2 (more strings here)"`
- `"string1 (more words)"`
- `"str1 str2 str3 [...] strn [...] (words. again.)"`

I want to end up with a `String[]` that looks like this:

```
["string1", "string2", "(more strings here)"]
```

Basically it should detect words and **everything** (also non characters) in round brackets as an individual group and put it in an String Array.

I understand that this captures the round brackets and their content: `(\((.*?)\))`
and this captures the words: `(\w+)`

but i have no idea how to combine them. Or is there a better alternative in Java?

Comment: Do the parenthesized strings always occur at the end, as all of your samples show, or can it also be `"string1 (more strings) string2"`? Can there be parentheses within the parentheses `"string1 (more (strings here))"`? Are you looking _only_ for parentheses ("round brackets") or can you also use pairs of `[]` and/or `{}`? (is your third sample `str3 [...] strn` just saying "and more strings"?) - aside: regex isn't necessarily the best tool for every job.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("([\\w]+|\\(.*?\\))");  // match continous word characters or all strings between "(" and ")"

    Matcher matcher =
            pattern.matcher("string1 (more words)");  // input string

    List<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // run matcher again and again to find the next match of regex on the input
    while (matcher.find()) { 
        stringArrayList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    String[] output = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);  // final output

    for (String entry :
            output) {
        System.out.println(entry);  // printing 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match the string with the following regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set), catching the matches in an array.

```
"\\([^)]*\\)|[a-z\\d]+"
```

[Start your Java engine!](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgICSo6KaCgw/index.html) (click "Java")

The following link to regex101.com uses the equivalent regex for the PCRE (PHP) engine. I've included that to allow the reader to examine how each part of the regex works. (Move the cursor around to see interesting details pop up on the screen.)

[Start your PCRE engine!](https://regex101.com/r/tTPByU/1/)